# Understanding of the definition "statistical experiment" (Blackwell, 1951)

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics, experimental-mathematics

I'm interesting for the understanding of the definition "statistical experiment".
Formally *statistical experiment*, *statistical model* or just *experiment* was defined as a triple 
$$\mathscr{P}=(\Omega,\mathscr{F}, \{ P_{\theta}:\theta \in \Theta \}),$$

where $\Omega,\mathscr{F}$ is a *sample space*, $\Theta$ is a *parameter spase* and $\{ P_{\theta}:\theta \in \Theta \}$ is ***family of probability measures***, defined on the given sample space.

My question is: why it is a family of probability measures? What is/are an example(s) of this abstaction?

Especially we could interesting for the parameters estimation. Let me give an example as the (real-valued) mean estimation problem of the random variables, that are normally distributed with known variance equals one. More precise: we have some i.i.d. r.v.'s $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ (given observations) with $X_1 \sim \mathscr{N}(\theta, 1)$. Then we could formulate related statistical experiment as $$\mathscr{P}=(\Bbb{R}^n,\mathscr{B}(\Bbb{R}^n), \{ P_{\theta}^{\times{n}}:\theta \in \Theta=\Bbb{R} \}).$$

So, we define our statistical experiment as the infinite set of possible distributions (i.e. as a set $\{\mathscr{N}(\theta, 1)^{\times{n}}:\theta \in \Bbb{R}\}$). Why do we need a set? Why we can not say, that we are looking for some estimation of the "true" distribution, which is unique?

Comment: You are looking for the value of $\theta$ that corresponds to the "true" distribution, but to do that you must consider a family of possible distributions. For example, you can make a modeling assumption that the value obtained when measuring the mass of an object is normally distributed with parameters $\mu$ (the true mass of the object) and $\sigma^2$. Then you estimate the value of $\mu$ from the observed data.

Comment: If you want an example of the use of that abstraction, you might try to continue to read the book. There are likely to be at least some examples that are more concrete, either in the later text or in the exercises.

Comment: How would you define the experiment with $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ without involving any kind of set of possible distributions? If you show your idea in your question, it might help you get some useful responses.